# Test reformatted text file method

Tags: ruby, minitest

So I am reformatting a txt file named pipe.txt from

```
Smith | Steve | D | M | Red | 3-3-1985
Bonk | Radek | S | M | Green | 6-3-1978
Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975
```

to

```
Bonk  Radek  S  Male  Green  6/3/1978
Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  Blue  6/3/1975
Smith  Steve  D  Male  Red  3/3/1985
```

And here is my code is app.rb for the output

```
def pipe
  alpha = File.readlines('pipe.txt').sort 
  alpha.each {|line| line.gsub! '-', '/'}
  alpha.each {|line| line.gsub! '|', ''}
  alpha.each {|line| line.gsub! 'M', 'Male'}
end
```

my test.rb looks like this at the moment

```
require_relative "app"
require 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/rg'


class AppTest < Minitest::Test

 def test_pipe_file
   pipe = File.open 'pipe.txt'
   assert_equal pipe, pipe
 end

 def test_space_file
   space = File.open 'space.txt'
   assert_equal space, space
 end

 def test_comma_file
   comma = File.open 'comma.txt'
   assert_equal comma, comma
 end

 def test_pipe_output1

 end


end
```

I want to write a test for my pipe method that reformats the txt files and make it pass. The method I wrote works I just need a test that shows that it works

Comment: Didn't get.. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I updated it, I'm trying to write a test that passes for my pipe method that reformats the text file

Comment: I would rewrite the `pipe` function to not read the file. This way, you can test it on a single string, while still having the functionality you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The following does not answer your question. Think of it as an extended comment.

If you apply your method with Mr. Bonk being Mr. Monk and Steve Smith being Billy-Bob Thornton, you'll see there are problems:

```
text =<<THE_END
Thornton | Billy-Bob | D | M | Red | 3-3-1985
Monk | Radek | S | M | Green | 6-3-1978
Bouillon | Francis | G | M | Blue | 6-3-1975  
THE_END

def pipe(lines)
  alpha = lines.sort
  alpha.each {|line| line.gsub! '-', '/'}
  alpha.each {|line| line.gsub! '|', ''}
  alpha.each {|line| line.gsub! 'M', 'Male'}
end

pipe(text.lines)
  #=> ["Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  Blue  6/3/1975  \n",
  #    "Maleonk  Radek  S  Male  Green  6/3/1978\n",
  #    "Thornton  Billy/Bob  D  Male  Red  3/3/1985\n"]
```

Consider doing it like this:

```
def pipe(lines)
  lines.sort.map { |line| line.sub(/\|\s+M\s+\|/,'Male')
                              .gsub(/(?<=\d)\-(?=\d)/,?/)
                              .delete(?|) }
end

pipe(text.lines)
  #=> ["Bouillon  Francis  G Male Blue  6/3/1975  \n",
  #    "Monk  Radek  S Male Green  6/3/1978\n",
  #    "Thornton  Billy-Bob  D Male Red  3/3/1985\n"]
```

Notes:

- `"M"` must be changed to `"Male"` before the `|`s are deleted, so that you can identify which `"M"` is to be replaced in each line.
- You forgot to change `"F"` to `"Female"` :-)
- `gsub`'s regex, `/(?<=\d)\-(?=\d)/` replaces hyphens preceded and followed by a digit with `/`. `(?<=\d)` is a "positive lookbehind"; `(?=\d)` is a "positive lookahead". This will ensure we don't mess with Mr. Thornton's first name.